# Making a span fill the height - even when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have two span divs that surround my content.  I want them to fill the height. `height: 100%;` works fine when there is no scrolling required, but once the page is long enough that the user needs to scroll the spans are only present for that first height and then do not fill the entire height.  Any ideas?  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fvcF/4/  Which for some reason doesn't even show the spans.

Comment: @Gustonez yes, as long as it isn't glitchy and works with IE and other evil browsers.  In the past I believe the jquery solutions I have seen are always glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements fall out of the mainstream.
You have to use something like [**this**](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(document).height()` in jQuery to make it work 100% height. E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#left').height($(document).height());
   $('#right').height($(document).height());

});
```

Comment: The page loads at size where all the content is in the window, but then there is a jQuery accordion that makes the page longer and scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_properties () {
    $('#left').css('height', function() {
        return $('#contentArea').innerHeight() + "px";
    });
    $('#right').css('height', function() {
        return $('#contentArea').innerHeight() + "px";
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(set_properties); 
    $(window).resize(set_properties);
    set_properties();   
});
```

OR change a little the CSS no need to use javascript/jQuery
you display the DIVs as table/cells.

```
#contentArea {
    width: 800px;
    display: table;
    color: #CCC;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #999;
    border-left-color: #999;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}


#contentArea #tc1,
#contentArea #tc3 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #F00;
}

<div id="contentArea">
  <div id="tc1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="tc2">
    <div class="header"> ... </div>
    <div class="ui-widget" style="margin: 0px;"> ... </div>
    <div class="main"> ... </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tc3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```